# Rhel kernel on Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-14.04, rhel

On my Ubuntu 14.04 server the kernel version is 2.6.32-042stab113.11
which is a rhel kernel version. How is this possible?
And please suggest ways to change this kernel to the latest kernel 3.19.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu 14.04 server is a virtual server running as an [OpenVZ](https://openvz.org/Main_Page) container. It is not a full, emulated virtual machine. As such, it does not have its own kernel. It uses the container host's kernel.

Comment: So is there a way in which I can make my processes use another kernel.

Comment: No, but various kernel features have been back-ported to the RHEL6-based OpenVZ kernels to support newer systems.

Comment: You could, of course, migrate your servers to another provider that runs servers as a proper VM, rather than a container.